# Redisgraph create index command timed out

Tags: redisgraph

Command is timing out when creating an index.
When I try to create an index on facilityNumber

> > GRAPH.QUERY GRAPH_NAME "CREATE INDEX ON :node(facilityNumber)"

I'm getting a timed out exception
`CLI ERROR: Command timed out. Blocking commands are not supported`

More Context:
My graph is constructed using redislab's bulk insert python script.
Graph consisting of 1214 nodes and 152846 relations.
`node` does contains `facilityNumber` when queried against.
With redisgraph running in docker, using image `redislabs/redismod`

Answer (score 1):

On which type of machine are you running docker?
also what happens when you switch to `redisgraph` docker image instead of `redislabs/redismod` ?